# Can't launch google-chrome-stable. Getting Out of date NSS (Libnss3)

Tags: google-chrome

I can't seem to open `google-chrome-stable`. When I attempt to launch the application I get the following:

```
[7465:7499:0911/174740.042852:FATAL:nss_util.cc(632)] NSS_VersionCheck("3.26") failed. NSS >= 3.26 is required. Please upgrade to the latest NSS, and if you still get this error, contact your distribution maintainer.
Aborted
```

I have run the following commands to fix:

```
sudo apt-get-upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libnss3
```

(That says I have the newest version.)

Here is what I get when I run `sudo apt-cache policy libnss3`:

```
libnss3:
  Installed: 2:3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.15.04.2
  Candidate: 2:3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.15.04.2
  Version table:
 *** 2:3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.15.04.2 0
```

I have uncommented everything in `/etc/apt/source.list`.

Comment: Looks like you're running 15.04, which hit end-of-life in Feb 2016. You will need to upgrade to a supported release like 16.04 or 17.04.

Comment: You can go through this tutorial: http://zakirrizvi.blogspot.com/2017/10/cant-lauch-google-chorme-stable-getting.html

Comment: The same problem exists on in-service releases, so this should be on-topic.  It has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46126902/86967

Answer (score 6):

If you are running 15.10 and below, the proper way is to upgrade the distro. However if you need to stick to your current version for whatever reason, here is *what I have done*.

I have force install the libnss3 from the upgraded version .deb file along with a dependency requirements.

---

Here is the dependency

```
sudo dpkg -i libnspr4_4.13.1-0ubuntu0.16.10.1_amd64.deb
```

from http://launchpadlibrarian.net/317146464/libnspr4_4.13.1-0ubuntu0.16.10.1_amd64.deb

---

Then, install the libnss3

```
sudo dpkg -i libnss3_3.26.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

from http://launchpadlibrarian.net/295856174/libnss3_3.26.2-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb

---

You still need to install one more, libnss3-nssdb, which is required for the Chrome as well

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -i libnss3-nssdb_3.26.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.2_all.deb
```

from http://launchpadlibrarian.net/296542005/libnss3-nssdb_3.26.2-0ubuntu0.16.04.2_all.deb

=====

I have taken the precaution by backing up these packages from system before installing the upgraded version in case something break and I cannot find the original .deb. In my case, I cannot find the deb for libnss3-nssdb

```
sudo apt-get install dpkg-repack
sudo dpkg-repack libnss3-nssdb
```

Comment: Wonderful. Solves the same issue on 14.04.5

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. This solved it.

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libnss3`

Answer (score 0):

**OS: Ubuntu 14.04**

Tried all the mentioned ways, none worked for me but following

- Click on ***Software & Updates***
- Go to ***Updates*** tab
- Check ***Important security updates***

  Enter the System Admin password. It will updates the cache.
  Once the process complete, you can launch the **Chrome Browser**.

[Reference](https://medium.com/@derrybernicahyady/problem-chrome-doesnt-work-nss-version-check-failed-ce7baec32930)

Comment: That didn't work for me on Ubuntu 15.10.

Answer (score 0):

if you are still failing to install or if it says libniss3 already to the latest version you can manually install it by following steps

1. Download it from the link->
   https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/amd64/libnss3/download
2. then move to the folder where you have downloaded the file in the terminal
3. install by running the following command in the terminal

> ```
> sudo dpkg -i libnss3_3.28.4-0ubuntu0.16.04.3_amd64.deb
> ```