# Chromium won't load up with my profile

Tags: 16.04, chromium

I have an issue with chromium not loading. It starts loading, but nothing opens up. I saw [another topic with similar issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466230/chromium-does-not-start-launch-seems-to-start-but-not-opening-the-application), which presented a seemingly good solution, except after logging into my google account, it syncs everything and next time I log out or restart or whatever, it won't load again, until I rename the chromium folder to something else.

Out of that information I make out that something in my profile is triggering it. An extension or something. I tried disabling them, but nada.

I don't know what else to do, as I'm relatively new to ubuntu (or any linux system), so I'm asking for help here.