# Some applications won't start

Tags: snap, chromium

I am running a virtual machine with Ubuntu 18.04, host is Win10. Since today, some applications do not start anymore. It prompted me an update this morning, which might be the issue. After clicking the icon, I see the top left bar working, but nothing happens. Known applications: System Monitor, Chromium, Snap. The same happens from the command line, when I do a `snap --version` or `chromium --version` for example. All other apps work fine. Best way to fix?

Edit: Also, the snap deamon does not seem to work.

```
to@ubuntu:~$ systemctl status snapd.service
● snapd.service - Snap Daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/snapd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2020-07-13 17:18:27 CEST; 1min 2s ago
  Process: 1617 ExecStart=/usr/lib/snapd/snapd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1617 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 13 17:18:27 ubuntu systemd[1]: snapd.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Jul 13 17:18:27 ubuntu systemd[1]: snapd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Jul 13 17:18:27 ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Snap Daemon.
Jul 13 17:18:27 ubuntu systemd[1]: snapd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Jul 13 17:18:27 ubuntu systemd[1]: snapd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jul 13 17:18:27 ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Snap Daemon.
Jul 13 17:18:27 ubuntu systemd[1]: snapd.service: Triggering OnFailure= dependencies.
```

Comment: start the applications from terminal to debug why they are unable to run. For example, type and enter `chromium` in terminal.

Comment: There's no output at all until I hit Ctrl+C after minutes

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466230/chromium-does-not-start-launch-seems-to-start-but-not-opening-the-application)?

Comment: Yes I did. I also read a bit more and tried to restart the snap deamon, there seems to be (at least part of) the issue. See edit of the question